# Flink - Postgres CDC connnector - custom query

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, debezium

I am working on the Flink application with Postgres DB as a source to read certain configuration data, convert it into a data stream and then join it with an incoming real-time data stream.

I have tried using [Postgres CDC connector](https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors), and I am able to read a single table and deserialize it into POJO and use it further.

However, my requirement is to read from **multiple tables using a join condition in the CDC source itself and then convert it into a data stream**. Can we write a custom query in the source? I could not find the possibility yet, the only solution I could think of is to then create multiple sources separately and then join those before finally joining with incoming real-time data. Can someone help here?

Regards,

Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

Could you solve your problem the other way around, by reading your incoming real-time data stream and then perform a lookup to the Postgres DB via the JDBC connector? The CDC connector is meant for monitoring changes happening in tables and send each change into Flink. I don't think there's a possibility to perform any joining in the CDC connector upfront.

Comment: The configuration data from Postgres could change and that needs to be captured, this is one of the reasons for choosing CDC. Since configuration data is stored in RDBMS,  it comes from many tables and hence the need to perform a join before converting into a stream. 
JDBC connection option - Is it possible to refresh the data from the JDBC connector once it is read into a stream ?

Comment: I still don't fully understand: what type of configuration data do you have in Postgres? What do you mean with needing to be captured? If you were to perform a lookup from your realtime stream, you would always get the latest configuration data from Postgres returned.